# ffmpeg command produces black image as output

Tags: ffmpeg

OS details:

[image: Output of cat /etc/os-release]

```
0

Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':

Duration: N/A, start: 13555.753906, bitrate: 147456 kb/s

Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 147456 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc

Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> mjpeg (native))


Press [q] to stop, [?] for help [swscaler @ 0x55fd0eafa3e0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly Output #0, image2, to 'test1.jpeg':

Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc), 640x480, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc

Metadata:
encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 mjpeg
Side data:
cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame= 1 fps=0.0 q=1.6 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=N/A speed=8.41x
video:3kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Command I used :

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -vframes 1 test1.jpeg
```

It produces black jpeg image as output. Why? Please suggest `ffmpeg` command to get webcam image.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Instead of screeenshot of OS details, paste the output of the terminal and format it appropriately.